# bash shell script prompting for database password

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I added a shell script I use all the time in cronjobs for a new account.  When I ran it (under sudo -u) I got prompted for the database password.  When supplied with pass the command completed without issue.

The random password the host had assigned started with a $ and I wondered if that was issue so I modified to have pass in variable. The current script is below.

When run it still prompts for db password before successfully completing.  What is wrong there?

```
#!/bin/sh

DBPASS="$randomlettersarehere"

/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -h mysql.mysite.com -u myuser -p$DBPASS mydbname > "/home/mysite/backups/"`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d`.mysiteBackup.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent `$letters` from being interpreted as a variable name.

```
DBPASS='$randomlettersarehere'
```

When you use double quotes the shell performs variable interpolation. With the dollar sign at the start, that means `$DBPASS` ends up being an empty string.

Comment: Haha - you beat me by 34 seconds!  Thank you.  Will accept as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else as derpy as I am:  use single quotes if string starts with $ so bash does not interpolate sring as undefined variable

`DBPASS='$randomlettersarehere'`